# Perl Script to Telnet to multiple IP and send a Reboot command, and print a confirmation to a log file

Tags: perl, telnet

I am trying to write a Perl Script (Never done it before).

Basically this script is to connect to a VoIP phone system and reboot the devices. I want it to connect to each sites device, reboot it and print the devices confirmation that a reboot is occurring or a connection error to a log file. I have no idea what I am doing with Perl and I do not even know if what I have so far is even remotely correct. It is just what I was able to find through digging around on google/forums.

What I want the script to do is the following:

I want the Perl Script to Telnet to a preset list of IP Addresses.

I want a .txt list of the IPs it will connect to (they all use the same login/password).
or is it possible to include the list within the actual Perl Script, that can be edited in the future to add/remove IP's?

Once the script telnet's, I want it to send the command 'reboot now' and then print the response to a log file along with the IP that it was connected to at the time it sent the command (The response when the command is issued is something like 'System is going down for a reboot now'). I want it to do this for each IP it connects to, and if it is unable to connect I want it to print an error along the lines of 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Unable to Connect'

So the log would look something like this:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.101 System going down for reboot
XXX.XXX.XXX.102 System going down for reboot
XXX.XXX.XXX.103 Unable to Connect
XXX.XXX.XXX.104 Unable to Connect
XXX.XXX.XXX.105 System going down for reboot
```

Is this possible to do?

I currently have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::Telnet;

my $log = './log.txt';

$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10,
Errmode=>'die'
Prompt => '/\$ $/i');
$telnet->open('IPADDRESS');
$telnet->login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
print $telnet->cmd('reboot now');
writef($log);
```

For the Prompt => do I need to change it to match whatever the symbol is that shows when you telnet and connect to the IP? The symbol I see is # so would the command be:

```
Promt => '/\# #/i);
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have SSH enabled on those devices? You need regular expression to match a prompt. If you have `#` or `something#` you can just use `/# $/`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::Telnet;

my $log = './log.txt';

open LOG, ">>$log";         #open log file - append mode
open IPS, "<ip.list";       #open ip.list file - read mode
while(<IPS>){
 my $ip = $_;               #current iteration (line) of IPs file
 $telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10,
         Errmode=>'die'
         Prompt => '/# $/i');
 $telnet->open($ip);
 $telnet->login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
 if($telnet->cmd('reboot now')){
  print LOG "$ip System going for reboot";
 }else{
  print LOG "$ip Unable to Connect";
 }
}
close LOG;                  #close files
close IPS;
```

The `ip.list` is just list of IPs, one per line.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.101
XXX.XXX.XXX.102
XXX.XXX.XXX.103
...
```

Comment: (First Line) 200AE2 Login:
(Second Line) System Password:
(Third Line) #

These are the three lines that show up when I telnet to one of the devices. Where I enter the Username, then Password. Then it goes to the # prompt, awaiting a command. Do all three of those entries need to be coded into the perl script?

Comment: Personally i would use the combination of `print()` and `waitfor()` methods. You can find the examples here: http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.04/lib/Net/Telnet.pm#EXAMPLES

Comment: `login()` method waits for `login` or `username` and responds with username you set, and then waits for `password` and responds with password. If it works for you you don't need to code anything else for logging in.

Comment: Aaah got it. I tried running it against one site, and it does not appear to be rebooting the device. I am not sure what the problem could be, as the log is writing this 'XXX.XXX.XXX.101 System going for Reboot'. But when I check the device, it is still running.

Comment: If you are logged in successfully try with `$telnet->print('reboot now');` instead of `cmd` and see if it works.

Comment: I think that it is logging in successfully. If it is printing to the log, then it must be logged in correct? If I put a bad IP in, i get an error that it can't connect. But for all the good IPs, it is printing to the log.